# Passing two parameters in action in Asp.net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass some json as string in an action but it only works for the first parameter.

Here is the action :

```
[HttpPost("testy")]
public string testyJson([FromBody] String json, [FromBody] String shortJson)
{
    dynamic o = MyModule.replaceInJson(json, shortJson);

    return "";
}
```

Here is the json I pass to both params :

```
"{\"id\":1}"
```

Here is the result 
[image]

More informations :

I'm using swagger to test my api, here is what I entered
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found : It's blocks by the framework for performances reasons. So i'll use a list of string containing my jsons.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation

[Binding formatted data from the request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body)

> **There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with**
>   `[FromBody]`. The ASP.NET Core MVC run-time delegates the
>   responsibility of reading the request stream to the formatter. Once
>   the request stream is read for a parameter, it's generally not
>   possible to read the request stream again for binding other
>   `[FromBody]` parameters.

(*emphasis mine*)

So the first parameter will get populated from the body but the second wont as the stream has already been read.

I would suggest creating a model to hold all the information to be passed to the action...

```
public class JsonModel {
    public string json { get; set;}
    public string shortJson { get; set;}
}
```

...and use that for the action parameter

```
[HttpPost("testy")]
public IActionResult testyJson([FromBody]JsonModel model) {
    var json = model.json;
    var shortJson = model.shortJson;
    dynamic o = MyModule.replaceInJson(json, shortJson);

    return Ok();
}
```